# Error with getting name:value pair from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

## I am trying to take a name:value pair from a json string

, although I am getting errors. I am using android Studio and java, and want to take that name:value pair and set a TextView to equal that value pair.

I believe the main problem is I may be taking the name:value pairs from the JSON incorrectly, and I also may be changing the TextView incorrectly.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    Log.v("s","--onResponse successfully called.");

    String mmessage = response.body().string();
    Log.v("s", "--Response: " + mmessage);

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mmessage);
        String api_info_balance = json.getString("balance");
        String api_info_pending_charges = json.getString("pending_charges");
        String api_info_last_payment_date = json.getString("last_payment_date");
        String api_info_last_payment_amount = json.getString("last_payment_amount");

         _balancetextview.setText(api_info_balance.toString());
         _pending_chargestextview.setText(api_info_pending_charges.toString());
         _last_payment_datetextview.setText(api_info_last_payment_date.toString());
         _last_payment_amounttextview.setText(api_info_last_payment_amount.toString());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("s", e.toString());
    }
}
```

### Here is the json returned:

> {"balance":"-23.66","pending_charges":"0.00","last_payment_date":"2017-01-27 14:52:13","last_payment_amount":"-50.00"}

Logcat:

```
    [ 11-11 15:34:08.755 16120:16186 D/         ]
                                                                                  SurfaceInterface::setAsyncMode: set async mode 1
11-11 15:34:08.762 16120-16186/com.example.sss.lesdothis D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9c98f8a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa8a8b7e0)
11-11 15:34:20.640 16120-16120/com.example.sss.lesdothis V/s: --button clicked.
11-11 15:34:22.142 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis V/s: --onResponse successfully called.
11-11 15:34:22.142 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis V/s: --Response: {"balance":"-23.66","pending_charges":"0.00","last_payment_date":"2017-01-27 14:52:13","last_payment_amount":"-50.00"}
11-11 15:34:22.143 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
11-11 15:34:22.144 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7286)
11-11 15:34:22.144 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1155)
11-11 15:34:22.144 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:21922)
11-11 15:34:22.145 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis I/chatty: uid=10082(u0_a82) i.vultr.com/... identical 5 lines
11-11 15:34:22.145 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:21922)
11-11 15:34:22.145 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1959)
11-11 15:34:22.145 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:21922)
11-11 15:34:22.145 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:8526)
11-11 15:34:22.145 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5392)
11-11 15:34:22.145 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5248)
11-11 15:34:22.145 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5205)
11-11 15:34:22.145 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at com.example.sss.lesdothis.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:113)
11-11 15:34:22.146 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
11-11 15:34:22.146 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
11-11 15:34:22.146 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
11-11 15:34:22.146 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
11-11 15:34:22.146 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
11-11 15:34:22.146 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis V/s: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
11-11 15:34:22.146 16120-16627/com.example.sss.lesdothis V/s: --pgld1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update the ui from the ui thread only as the stacktrace states. You can do so by calling `runOnUiThread` method if you're in an activity:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    _balancetextview.setText(api_info_balance.toString());
    _pending_chargestextview.setText(api_info_pending_charges.toString());
    _last_payment_datetextview.setText(api_info_last_payment_date.toString());
    _last_payment_amounttextview.setText(api_info_last_payment_amount.toString());
}
});
```

Basically just wrap your UI updates in the call to this method and it won't crash anymore. Here's the [link to the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) if you wanna know more.

Comment: Hi @Vucko, thank you for your suggestion. However I am still getting errors https://hastebin.com/eyequmipuh.swift

Comment: What's the error? Might be a new one. Also why `api_info_balance.toString()` ? When `api_info_balance` is already a string. So `toString()` is obsolete.

Comment: Hey @Vucko I do not know where to put the runOnUiThread, wherever I wrap it, it causes errors saying it shouldn't be there.

Comment: `runOnUiThread` method is found in the `Activity` class. If you're in a fragment, you can do `getActivity().runOnUiThread()`. If you're in some completely other class, than your separation of concerns is not good. But since you have UI elements here, I'd assume it must be the fragment.